# Segmentation fault during thread.join

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I have a problem with my code. When I'm increasing argv[1] to 4.294.967.295 (INT_MAX) I'm getting a segmentation fault, although I chose 'long long int' as data type:

```
#define NUM_THREADS 5

// ...

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    // allocating memory and declaring threads
    std::thread thread[NUM_THREADS];    
    bool *sv_ptr = (bool *) calloc(atoll(argv[1]), sizeof(bool));

    short int t = 0;
    long long int i = 2;

    // initialize threads
    for (t = 0; t < NUM_THREADS; t++, i++)
        thread[t] = std::thread(remove_multiples, i, sv_ptr, atoll(argv[1]));

    t = 0; 
    while (i < atoll(argv[1]) || !threads_finished(thread))
    {
        if (sv_ptr[i] || thread[t].joinable())
        {
            // starting new tasks
            if (thread[t].joinable())
            {
                thread[t].join(); // <- segfault occurs here
                thread[t] = std::thread(remove_multiples, i, sv_ptr, atoll(argv[1]));
            }

            // printing results
            if (!sv_ptr[i-NUM_THREADS])
                std::cout << (i - NUM_THREADS) << std::endl;

            i++;
        }
        // increment thread iterator
        t = (t + 1) % NUM_THREADS;
    }
    // ...
}

void remove_multiples(long long int n, bool *sv_ptr, long long int max)
{
    for (int i = 2; i*n < max; i++)
    sv_ptr[i*n] = true;
}

bool threads_finished(std::thread *threads)
{
    for (int t = 0; t < NUM_THREADS; t++)
        if (!threads[t].joinable())
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

The segmentation fault occurs on joining a joinable thread.

Thank you for your help!

edit: I wanted to test heap allocation on my 16 GB machine, therefore I wrote this program. I'm able to create an array of ~1.5 trillion bools and I did this with a single-thread program before.
**The error doesn't occur on allocation! I have enough memory. It occurs somewhere in the thread management**

Comment: This code segment is just for initializing all NUM_THREADS threads.
I'm iterating through the array in the while loop.

Comment: `bool *sv_ptr = (bool *) calloc(atoll(argv[1]), sizeof(bool));` I hope you're on 64-bit and have a lot of RAM, considering that would allocate at least 4 GB, and maybe 16 GB. Sure that's right?

Comment: Side note: Keep variables as local as possible (in terms of declaration and usage) (eg,: for(short int t = 0; ...)) and avoid recycling variables for in a different context.

Comment: i wanted to test heap allocation and therefore I wanted to use my whole memory (16 GB)

Comment: @J.Doe I can't see things going well if your "whole capacity" is 16 GB and you're trying to allocate a 16 GB contiguous memory chunk.

Comment: sorry, nearly my whole memory*
with my single thread program I allocated ~14 GB (1.5 billion bools)
My OS only needs about 1 GB

Comment: @J.Doe, have you tried debugging your program? Accessing what address causes a segfault? I see at least one potential segfault in your program: `calloc` fails and returns NULL, one of threads grabs it and tries to access in `remove_multiples`. Boom. Segfault.

Comment: I tried to debug it and all worked until thread[t].join is called the first time.

Comment: You should sanitize your code. This includes localising variables (see Dieter Lücking's comment), and asserting `sv_ptr!=nullptr`. Also, in a C++ program you shouldn't use raw memory allocations like `calloc()`.

Comment: How can I allocate memory on the heap without calloc? With other local definition my variables will be put on the stack which is hardly limited in size.

Answer (score 1):

ok I ran this code in my debugger (after re-arranging the function order and adding missing include files so it would compile).

For me the segfault occurs at the end of the program. I strongly suspect that the logic in this function is incorrect:

```
bool threads_finished(std::thread *threads)
{
    for (int t = 0; t < NUM_THREADS; t++)
        if (!threads[t].joinable())
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

for two reasons:

1. you're returning false (i.e. no, not finished) if any thread is NOT joinable, and
2. you can't detect whether a thread has finished like this. You need to get the threads to update an atomic counter/flag set or better, a flag set protected by a condition variable and mutex pair so you can correctly (a) test whether a thread is complete and (b) wait for all threads to complete before `main()` ends.

update:

added reference as requested. Suggest you bookmark this site.

> A thread that has finished executing code, but has not yet been joined is still considered an active thread of execution and is therefore joinable.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/joinable

Comment: Thank you, that's the first helpful answer.

1. If there exists a thread that is not joinable, then not all threads are 'finished'. Else they are. I think the logic is correct

2. How should I check it, do you have any references?

Comment: First thank you for the reference, I'll bookmark it. But it looks like the method is correct isn't it? "Checks if the thread object identifies an active thread of execution." So when the thread has is done with removing multiples it's joinable and therefore looking for a new task.

Comment: A thread is `joinable` both when it is running AND when it has finished executing. It is only `not joinable()` when it has been default initialised, moved from, moved-to with a default-initialised object or `release()`d.

Comment: oh, now I'm getting your point... I should really get more into this topic. The given program was my first try in multithreading.

Comment: Note - to expeienced multithreaded developers, 'join/joinable' is about as welcome as an STD.   'The error doesn't occur on allocation! I have enough memory. It occurs somewhere in the thread management' - yes, this is exactly what happens when you try to micro-manage threads.